# Public Function Return VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am starting to think more about using Functions to prevent me from writing the same code over and over but the more I read about them the more confused I am getting.

Here is a function I have placed inside a Module which basically gets the path to a folder under the AppData Local folder for the current User.

```
Public Function AppDataLocal() As String
    
    Dim AppData As String() = {GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyApp"}
    Dim AppDataFullpath As String = Path.Combine(AppData)
    Return AppDataFullpath

End Function
```

Anytime I want find the path I am calling the function like this.

```
MsgBox(AppDataLocal)
```

Everything appears to be working but I would like to know if I am doing it correctly and also why I need to have the line **Return AppDataFullpath** in the Function. Without this line Visual Studio shows a squiggly line under **End Function**.

Comment: Before doing a question like that there is required a minimum searches by OP around the issue.
However, here is your answer :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/function-statement

Comment: Function returns some data, a sub does not. so if you have a function that does return 2+2=5 and in another place dim mytotal as integer = myfunction, your mytotal would be 5

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Docs. I had read that but found myself going round in circle if I am honest

Comment: The explanation from jmcilhinney was perfect for a novice like me to understand and I have taken this on board especially the bit about naming.

Comment: It’s not to discredit but motivate people. By doing researches you can learn much more than an answer on a certain question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing is basically correctly, although I'd do it slightly differently.

The idea of a function is that it is a chunk of code identified by a name that does some work and then produces a value that you can use elsewhere in your code. In VB, a subroutine (identified by the `Sub` keyword) is similar but it does work without producing a value. The `Return` statement in the function is what tells the system what value the function produces. A subroutine generally has no `Return` statement or, if it does, no value is specified and it just indicates that the method should end at that point.

While it's not wrong to provide a `String` array to `Path.Combine`, it's parameter is actually declared as a `ParamArray`, which means that you can pass discrete values and the system packages them as a single array. That means that you could do this:

```vb
Dim AppData As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
Dim AppDataFullpath As String = Path.Combine(AppData, "MyApp")
Return AppDataFullpath
```

To be honest, I'd simplify that right down to a single line:

```vb
Return Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyApp")
```

Also, you should keep in mind that properties are data and methods are behaviour, so property names should be noun-based and method names should be verb-based. As such, that method would be better named `GetLocalAppDataPath` or the like. That is more self-documenting than what you currently have.